# cant install brackets from .deb file

Tags: deb

Can not install brackets from .deb file. 
 Please help someone.

[image]

[image]
Its solved.

Comment: What Ubuntu version ?

Comment: ubuntu 15.10   installed it 2 days ago.

Comment: its my first time on ubuntu. please make it easy.

Comment: Have you tried installing `libgcrypt11` which is the missing dependency?

Comment: how do i install libgcrypt11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the dependency `libgcrypt11` so install it

Open a terminal and run these commands

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

When it finishes downloading run

```
sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.3-2ubuntu4.2_amd64.deb
```

To install the package, when it finishes, install your deb again

Comment: sir i think libgcrypt11 is already installed. it shows in green in synaptic package manager. i uploaded the picture.

Comment: No, the development libraries are installed `libgcrypt11` isn't `libgcrypt11-dev`

Comment: And you have to remove `libgcrypt11-dev` first.